# Encrypt and decrypt messages between two systems

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, data-integrity

I have the following system

Android app -> kafka -> listener service (Java).

I would like to make sure that there is data integrity in this process.

I want to encrypt the message in the Android app, insert it into a topic and then have listener pick it up and decrypt the message.

I would like to know what would be the best way (algorithm and practice) to encrypt and decrypt between the systems. Can this be achieved in a simple way (without certs or keys)?

Assuming there will be 5 mobile apps pushing messages to the broker.

Comment: How many apps will communicate with the listener service? Do they need each their own key? If your client is made to speak only with the listener, it can hold it's public key and doesn't need any certification authority.

Comment: Encryption by itself won't offer you data integrity. Message data integrity can be delivered using a an authentication tag over the messages, but you probably need more than that. Try to look up e.g. CMS signed / encrypted messages.

Comment: Well encryption works with either certs or keys. So "*without certs or keys*" is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to make sure that there is data integrity in this process.

If you are concerned to ensure the message integrity during transport, using TLS (ssl, https) would do the trick in the most of the cases. If you need end-to-end security (signed, encrypted message) between other components (kafka->Java), you will need to sign the message. In most of the cases you should be ok with the first option (https).

> Can this be achieved in a simple way (without certs or keys)?

PKI (certs and keys) enables us to ensure integrity and confidentiality without hardcoding the secrets (which is not very wise for mobile apps). You already have out of box libraries for SSL, so consider it "the simple way". Building custom protocol to sign and validate the messages is only more complex and possibly less secure.

> I would like to know what would be the best way (algorithm and practice) to encrypt and decrypt between the systems.

For basic transport security, I'd suggest to rely on TLS, you still need to authenticate the user (username, password?) to ensure client's identity. TLS provides secure channel up to the SSL termination point (https server, kafka listener, ..).

If you need end-to-end security (signed, encrypted message) between other components (kafka->Java), there are some standards to encrypt and sign the messages, such as WS-Security for web services or you can use signed and encrypted JWT to pass messages.

However - you will have to securely exchange the keys between the client and validating backend (with a separate service or some key exchange protocol).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to implement that is to use and encrypted channel using some secure transport (https, sftp, etc.)

If you are implementing a custom protocol, then you will need to encrypt/decrypt the messages using some of the available libraries.

And yes, I suggest to use an standard encryption algorithm (which will require to use certificates).